# close vote not count if close from question page

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, voting

I was reviewing `Close Vote` and to check detail of the question, if we open question and close from the question page `close` link in bottom of the question then it will not count in the total close vote.

Please check below screenshots for detail.

I opened question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869079/my-python-script-doesnt-do-anything-but-it-runs from `Close Vote` page. (Count for close vote was `983`)

[image: Close Vote question list]

Then I checked question by clicking on its link and click on `close`.

[image: Close vote in question page]

After closing question, it shows question is closed by me.

[image: Close vote done from question page]

If I check from `Close Vote` review page then it shows, post is closed, but count of close votes is still `983`.

[image: Close Vote page with same score]

Comment: Surely this has nothing to do with that impending Steward badge? ;)

Comment: @jonsca badge might be part of review only ;)

Comment: By the way, this is not the count of close votes, this is the count of reviews performed. Clicking Leave Open or Edit also increases the count, because they are review actions. As the answer said, if you are not on review page, then you are not reviewing - you are just voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're saying you should be able to close the question twice? This is status-bydesign, so that if you already voted to close on a question outside of the review queue, you can't vote on it inside the queue too. That's why it didn't give you credit for the review since you weren't eligible to review it at that point.

As you'll notice, you are never shown questions in the close queue that you have previously voted to close. Whether you voted on it 1 hour ago, two days ago, or a year ago. You are only eligible to do close reviews on questions that you haven't already voted to close.

So if you want credit for a review, you need to do the action in the queue, not outside of it.

Comment: Let me write what I understand, credit for review will be given only if it will be review from review queues. If you review outside the review queue then credit will be not given. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Lafada that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for explain in detail :)