# Close votes outside Close Vote queue should count towards Reviewer/Steward badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'd like to let something out of my chest that's been annoying me since I got access to the [Close Vote Review Queue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/close). Maybe someone can shed a light on the topic.

I'm an enthusiastic fan of the [First Post review queue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts). There, sometimes, the Right Thing To Do (TM) is to just vote to close the question. It's either an outright request for product or about fixing a device. Plain and simple.

However, if I vote to close it, **that vote won't count towards my Reviewer/Steward badges for Close Vote review queue**. That really annoys me. The result is that I would either click **Skip** or **No Action Needed**, wait for someone to vote to close the question and then cast my close vote by visiting the Close Vote review queue.

That's really annoying because I feel cheated. I performed a perfectly valid Close Vote review (even though it's outside the queue), so I think it should count towards those badges. Moreover, it forces me not to do the right thing on the First Post queue.

There's been some arguments about the issue. Below are a few links I gathered from a few meta stacks:

- [Close Votes Outside the Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258100/close-votes-outside-the-queue)
- [Close vote not count if close from question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239485/close-vote-not-count-if-close-from-question-page)
- [How do close votes count towards the reviewer badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148062/how-do-close-votes-count-towards-the-reviewer-badge)

Some folks argue that voting to close outside the queue should not count towards the badge because the symmetrical review, deciding not to close a post, wouldn't count outside the queue either. That's just silly! There's no such symmetry. If I vote to close a question outside the queue, well, I just did a close vote review, exactly like I would have done in the queue (for that particular question, that is). For that reason, **I think it should count towards my badge.** It's pointless to compare with the **Leave Open** decision on the **First Post** queue.

As a result of this reasoning, I think the kind folks at SE.EE should consider **counting the votes to close outside the Close Votes review queue towards the Close Votes Reviewer and Steward badge.**

Do you agree with me?

Comment: I don't even bother with the first post queue. 90% of the time, people make trivial edits, or just click "looks good." I I'll clear out the other queues periodically, but mainly just watch the main page.

Comment: @MattYoung I guess that watching the main page is an option, but reviewers looking for the badge are still discouraged from voting to close from there. The First Post queue is still very convenient for catching pearl's from new users, be it a question or answer.

Comment: There's the difference, I don't give a rat's ass about the badges.

Comment: @MattYoung I agree, reputation and badges aren't really important. But they exist to encourage users to contribute in meaningful ways to the sites. They are so carefully though out and work so well in SE that when something is out of place, it stands out.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on meta.stackexchange?